# Opening a saved WPF application in Visual Studio doesn't show any code or designer window

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2013

I m very new to VS, i recently saw a youtube video of making a simple web browser, and i tried it, it came well. and then i saved it.

later i thought of adding another button to it, so i tried to open the saved file in VS, but unfortunately it came empty with 
No properties tab on right,
No WPF tool tab on left,
No design box and No code box..

when i press, F5 (run) it gives out the browser window, but when i press F7 (code window) it gives nothing..

How to get those tabs back, to continue my work..
Any Help is appreciated..

Comment: Did you open it from Folder or from the program?

Answer (score 1):

In the View menu, select Solution Explorer. You should be able to double click your code files there to open them up.

Comment: View > Toolbox (Ctrl W,X by default)